# SEO for Audio Files

Tags: seo, audio

I have a new client who runs an internet radio station. His site has hundreds of previously recorded shows and I would like to optimize the audio files for SEO as much as possible.

I've consider doing the following:

- [Add schema.org markup](https://schema.org/RadioEpisode).
- Add [ID3 tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3) to the audio files themselves.
- Name the files descriptively.

The question that I have is, what are other ways to optimize audio files for SEO?

Note: I've consider transcribing each radio episode so search engines can see the transcripts but that would be either too time consuming or cost too much to hire a person/company to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple and effective way.

Transacribe the audios and post it below the audio file. You will have unique content + more data for the search engines to fetch more traffic to the site.

Use services like Fiverr to get the transcribed. Very good method for long term.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Transcription would be great and will be an option for some episodes but the site has over 4,000 hours of archived audio files with several hours of audio produced every week. Not something that is easily doable for most audio files.

Comment: In that case, you need to do the reverse engineering. What I mean is, sort of the titles you have and find the high searches keywords.

So for the high searches keywords find out the auidos which has less than 10 minutes of audo. Transcript that and this is a like a pillar articles and from that give interlinks to the long audio files. 

That might works, and quite tedious still works.